# Reduce the size of PDF file generated with Quartz2D

Tags: iphone, pdf, pdf-generation, quartz-2d

I'm looking for a way to reduce PDF size that I generate with Quartz. I'm drawing images with CGContextDrawImage in a CGPDFContext. What I'm afraid of is that the images are saved as Bitmap and not JPEG. Is there a way to check for that and a way to control that when writing the PDF?

I also tried reducing downscaling the image before writing it to the PDF context but I end up with an even larger file (although the page size in pixels is smaller).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you name a few characteristics of what you are drawing, where the images come from and how large the resulting files are? Did you pass a file to a external pdf compression tool and had a look at the differences?

Comment: The images are camera images, stored as JPEG and then read to UIImage objects. So I draw a UIImage.CGImage in the CGPDFContext. File size would be for instance 1.2 MB for a single page. If I try to downscale, I goes up to 3 MB. With a compression tool (quartz filter) it's more like 500KB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for setting `CGPDFContext`'s image compression settings.

Comment: I also tried another library with compression settings available. The pattern seems similar: the size of the image doesn't matter much compared to the size of the PDF page.

Comment: Perhaps try reducing the color depth on the `CGImage` that you're writing? A 16-bit image will be half the size _if_ `CGPDFContext` stores images in their source formats

Comment: I looked into that but couldn't find any API to reduce the depth of a CGImage. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: Create a `CGBitmapContext` in the format you want, draw into it, then pull your new image out using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur if you need to reduce PDF on the *iPhone* or if it's acceptable for you to reduce them on a PC/Mac.

On PC/Mac, **[Adobe Acrobat Pro](http://www.Adobe.com/Acrobat9)** (a commercial product not to be mistaken with *Adobe Reader*) has a **PDF optimizer**. Menu "Adavanced" > "PDF Optimizer...". This can downscale images, fonts, etc. As there is also a [command-line interface (using AutoBatch)](http://www.evermap.com/autobatch.asp). It isn't cheap but it's probably the best PDF compressor out there.